# How to call cloud function in Parse.com after user logged in or signed up

Tags: parse-platform

In Cloud code, I can call afterSave function for User Class after any update for this class.

However, I need to call cloud function ONLY after user logged in of after signed up

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method like `afterSave` for login/signup. What you could do is write a regular cloud function and call it from the client after the user logged in or signed up in your app.

As you did not name the platform you are developing on, here are all relevant documentation links on how to call cloud functions from the client.

iOS
https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#cloudfunctions/iOS

Android
https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#cloudfunctions

JavaScript
https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#cloudfunctions

PHP
https://parse.com/docs/php_guide#cloudfunctions

Unity
https://parse.com/docs/unity_guide#cloudfunctions

.Net
https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#cloudfunctions

REST-API
https://parse.com/docs/rest#cloudcode